# In Shiny, how can I update dependent inputs automatically?

Tags: r, input, shiny, updating

I'm creating a Shiny app that allows a user to load existing input data from a list. However, what I find is that only the independent inputs are being updated while the inputs that are dependent on other inputs remain blank. Here is the code that updates the inputs upon an observeEvent action button:

```
observeEvent(input$load_project, {  #observes the actionButton load_project

projects = Your_projects()   #a reactive with list of input names and values
project_names = projects[[1]]
projects_data = projects[[3]]      

project_inputs = projects_data[[input$your_projects]]
nInputs = length(project_inputs)
nameInputs = names(project_inputs)
for(k in 1:4){ #hoping if it loops several times the dependent inputs would 
                             #appear but no luck
for(i in 1:nInputs){ #loop through all of the inputs
Type = typeof(project_inputs[[i]]) #get type of input
if(Type == "character"){ 

  updateTextInput(session,nameInputs[i],NULL,value = project_inputs[[i]])

}
}}
})
```

The code works for updating independent inputs but not dependent inputs. If I create similar code for observing the event of a "refresh_inputs" button and press it then the dependents inputs are updated. But I'd like an automated way to do it.

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: More context would be helpful. How are your "dependend" inputs generated? Are you using `renderUI` od `conditionalPanel`s? This might just be a race condition in which case the `priority` argument of `observe` will be helpful.